# Framework to handle recurring tasks

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, windows-services

We implemented a windows service that has a couple of timers in it. Over time the logic for the timers got more and more complicated. Its time to refactor our solution and one possible way would be to use a well documented framework that handles our requirements.

There are rules like:

- start timer A each day at 9am
- start timer B each 2min
- if timer A is started dont start any other timer
- timer C and D are not allowed to run at the same time

I looked at Quartz.net because it had the first 2 requirements of our list, but it doesnt handle any concurrency rules.

Is there any framework I could have a look at?

Comment: Not an answer but Quartz.NET is quite good. It would be fairly trivial to implement the concurrency rules yourself.

Comment: My favorite thing about Quartz is that you can use crontab format to describe your timings which I am familiar with: http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/crontrigger

Answer (score 2):

I had similar requirements: essentially what you need is a **state machine** that can be easily serialized to disk or a database, some way to specify the state machine easily using hierarchical states, some way to easily specify temporal events (*After*, *Every*, *At*) and some way to easily know when to load the state machine back into memory to advance state based on the current time.

In the end I wrote my own state machine as I didn't find one that met my requirements, in particular the temporal events and the serialization requirements.  You can get the source code in a [Nuget Package](https://nuget.org/packages/AboditStateMachine/0.1.1353).  Blog entry [here](http://blog.abodit.com/2012/04/building-a-better-net-state-machine/).  Feedback welcome.